# Oracle Apex how to change map background dynamically

Tags: maps, oracle-apex

I cannot figure out how to change map background dynamically based on user input.

I want for user to pick value in the list of values or select a checkbox or anything along the lines and map back ground to change for one to another one.

However, I wasn't able to figure out it out by myself or find anything related online.